# Search in Laravel after eager loading the records?

Tags: php, search, laravel, laravel-4, eager-loading

I have a `flights` table which has two foreign key columns: origin and destination, both of them are linked to `airports` table. Now I can eager load the records fine:

```
Flight::with('origin', 'destination')->get();
```

But now I want to do something like:

```
Flight::with('origin', 'destination')->where('origin.name', 'LIKE', "$query%")->get();
```

But it is giving me an error saying that there is no column by the name of `origin.name` which is making sense to me but how do I search records within the eager loaded data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`whereHas` should work:

```
Flight::with('origin', 'destination')->whereHas('origin', function($q) use ($query){
    $q->where('name', 'LIKE', "$query%");
})->get();
```

Comment: Although I get the drift of most of the things happening here, I never understand what the `use` is for and how it implemented. I am aware it is a part of name spaces in PHP which have always confused me. Why can't I just pass the `$query` variable in the parameters. I know my question might sound stupid, but there still some things that beat my understanding.

Comment: No it doesn't really have something to do with namespaces. It's the **variable scope**. You see, local variables, like `$query` are not available in closures (aka. anonymous functions) because the have their own variable scope. With `use` you declare that you want to use the variable available inside the closure.

Comment: I guess it makes more sense now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you need a closure to make it right. Here's a simple example.

```
$places = Flight::with(array('origin' => function($query) use($query_name)
{
 $query->where('name', 'LIKE', "$query_name%");
}))->get();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This doesn't filter flights by a certain origin name but only *loads* the origin when the condition is true.